# How can I predict links in box.net?

Tags: file, hosting, box-api

I'm a new user on box.net site and I've uploaded A LOT of .zip files that I want to use in my project.
The problem is that, normally, the share link is something like: box.net/1.zip .. so I can predict that the 100th file will be box.net/100.zip ... but this is not the case in box.net..
I cant obviously copy every files link manually since what I uploaded and need is ~1000 small .zip files and copying each files link will take ages.
So is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

We recently released a new feature, where you can give your share a custom name.  See the [blog entry for more details](http://blog.box.com/2012/08/customize-to-your-hearts-content-introducing-custom-links/) on how to use it.

Right now, we have not exposed an API to set these custom links, but that will be coming soon.